# How to ask a wondering question to make a listener deduce the answer

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

How can someone ask a wondering question to make a listener deduce the answer?

Here are a couple of examples to demonstrate what I mean:

> A: Is he sad because he lost 1 Bitcoin?
>   B: He was extremely sad because he lost a couple of dollars yesterday so **how would a Bitcoin be?!** (or **what about a Bitcoin?!**)

Second example:

> A: Did son gave his mother an expensive present?
>   B: Last week, he gave a friend a very valuable present so **how about his beloved mother?!**

I'd like to ask those questions Colloquially (not formal) and a U.S. answer is preferable. Forgive me if I wrote a completely wrong question words. I don't know the right ones.

Comment: Did the son give [check your verb usage]. That is a very basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

> He was extremely sad because he lost a couple of dollars yesterday so **how would a Bitcoin be**?! (or **what about a Bitcoin?!**)

Both versions are not quite conventional English. You could perhaps said said:

> Yesterday, he was extremely sad when he lost a couple of dollars, so you can imagine how sad he would be to lose an entire Bitcoin?!

.

> Last week, he gave a friend a very valuable present **so how about his beloved mother?!**

Once again, this is not quite conventional English. You could perhaps said said:

> Last week, he gave a friend a very valuable present, so you can imagine how generous he will be to his own beloved mother?!

I note that you have used both an exclamation mark (!) and a question mark (?) at the end of your sentences. This is not a common practice with most English speakers, although some people do  this. Generally, English speakers only use either a single question or a single exclamation mark, depending on the requirements of the sentence. If a sentence asks an exclamatory question, then English speakers usually only use an exclamation mark. Incidentally, the use of both marks at the end of a sentence is referred to as an **interrobang**. Some keyboards, and some word processors have combined both marks into a single character which looks like this '‽'.